# regex split problem

Tags: javascript, regex

I have javascript string variable with

```
var sttr="We prefer questions that can be answered --------------------- not just discussed ---------------------
Provide details ---------------------------- Write clearly and simply --------------------------answer all the question"
```

please suggest how to split the string into array of sentences on the basis of dashes(-----) **using regex**

result should be

```
array[0]=We prefer questions that can be answered
array[1]=not just discussed
array[2]=Provide details
array[3]=rite clearly and simply
array[4]=answer all the question
```

**Note**: dash(-----) range after each sentence is between 10 to 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split on `/-{10,50}/g`.

#### See also

- [regular-expression.info/Limiting repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- [Javascript regular expressions methods and usage](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

sttr.split(/-+/g);

Test it with [regular expression tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm)